# AWS Auth update failed stuck on UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-signin, aws-amplify

I've added the google sign in to my app and tried to push the modifications, however I didn't have permissions to do that. After I got the permissions, I tried to amplify push but I get this error:

```
Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:432853258441:stack/amplify-huruproject-local-190356/117b7360-c94d-11eb-a4cc-0e8a861a6983 is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state and can not be updated.
```

An error occurred during the push operation: Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:432853258441:stack/amplify-huruproject-local-190356/117b7360-c94d-11eb-a4cc-0e8a861a6983 is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state and can not be updated.

Thing is I can't find this specific stack in my stacks console. How can I fix this?
UPDATE:
I found the stack, it was in an autogenerated nested stack.
this is what I found:
[image]

[image]
[image]

I don't know how to proceed from here. should I delete the whole stack? Will I lose all my data?

Comment: To find it in your CloudFormation console, make sure you select "Failed" in the stack selection dropdown, not "Active". And make sure you're in the right account/region.

Comment: hi, I checked the Failed, Deleted and In Progress sections plus I am in the right region but nothing shows, i even contacted the admin but nothing shows on his account too.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct account? `432853258441` in `us-east-1`?

Comment: yes, 'US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1' and account 432853258441, the last stack in failed dates back to september, no record whatsoever of the one mentioned above. UPDATE: I found it nested in this old stack .

Comment: What does `aws cloudformation list-stacks` output?

Comment: I dont have the aws cli installed, only the amplify one

Comment: Try installing it. Make sure it uses the same account/region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-update-rollback-failed/), you can either delete the stack or try continuing the rollback. The simplest solution would be to just delete the stack and try again.

Here's the summary:

> If your stack is stuck in the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state after a failed update, then the only actions that you can perform on the stack are the ContinueUpdateRollback or DeleteStack operations. This is because CloudFormation requires further input from you to acknowledge that the stack is out of sync with the template that the stack is attempting to roll back to. To retry the rollback and resolve the error, you can use ContinueUpdateRollback.

> Tip: To resolve the error, you might need to raise limits, change permissions, or modify other settings. For information on common errors that cause update rollback failures, see Update rollback failed.

> In some cases, retrying the rollback doesn't resolve the error. In these cases, you must skip resources, and also acknowledge that these resources no longer reflect the desired state in the CloudFormation template. To skip the resources that caused the rollback failures, complete the following steps in the Resolution section.

As for the cause of the error - you can see from the CloudFormation messages that the `readAttributes` and `writeAttributes` of a `UserPoolClient` cannot be empty, like they are in your case.

Comment: But won't all of my data ( I have userpools and dynamodb datastore)and configuration be lost like that ?

Comment: Did you read the link in the answer? I added the summary to the answer.

Comment: AWS error message is holy unfriendly, incorrect. You saved my day !

Answer (score 16):

A little late to reply but I'll just put this here for future reference. Deleting the stack or continuing are the only two options you have when you hit the "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_STATE". But **don't go deleting the stack right away**.

### STEP 01.

- Try Continuing the Update.
  [image]

### STEP 02.

- If it still goes to the "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_STATE", click "Continue Update Rollback" again
- Expand "Advanced Trouble shooting" and check the resources to skip. (You will probably have to check them all)
- Then click "continue Update Rollback"

[image]

### Step 03

- After step 02, you should be at a "Update Rollback Success" state.
- Before deploying again, try to find out the cause for the failure.
- For me it was deploying a service with Node V10 and it wasn't supported for AWS Lambda deployment no more.
- Fix what ever is causing the deployment issue and redeploy.

### STEP 04

- Sadly if non of the above steps worked, then you will have to delete the stack.
- This is a nuisance especially if you're using services like API Gateway or DynamoDB streams. You'll have to update all the relevant links in your front-end afterwards.

Comment: in my case with AWS Amplify, I needed to select only name of the lambda function in Step 2.